# multi-key argsort in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

say I have

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 1], 'b': [2, 1, 3, 3]})
```

I'd like to find an Expr  indices such that
`df.sort(indices)` would give the same result as `df.sort(by=['a', 'b'])`

110% hacky solution:

```py
pl.from_pandas(df.to_pandas().sort_values(['a', 'b']).index.to_series())
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution from the Polars Discord (thanks orlp!)

```py
>>> df.sort(df.select(pl.arg_sort_by(pl.col('a'), pl.col('b'))))
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘
>>> df.sort(by=['a', 'b'])
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘
```